# SLIM Framework post variables always null

Tags: rest, post, slim

I am using SLIM Framework with a simple post route function like:

```
$app->post( '/addresses', 'addAddress' );

...

function addAddress() 
{
    global $app;
    $request = $app->request();
    $firstname = $request->params('firstname');
    echo $firstname;
   /* insert into action ... */
}
```

and want to get the post variables, but if I sent a post request with the Advanced Rest Client for Chrome like the following:

```
firstname=Test
```

the result is always null :(

**EDIT:** 
the mistake was text/plain if I set it up to application/x-www-form-urlencoded it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was to select text/plain for Advanced Rest Client, if I set it up to application/x-www-form-urlencoded it works